# Импорт таблицы Excel'я в html.

Tags: php, excel, javascript

Достаточно бредово, но неукротима мысль узверя...

Знает ли кто способы импорта? Хоть какие-то. Но больше всего интересуют на php или JS.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, ответ можно найти тут: [**excel php**][1].


  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=Excel+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&sugexp=llsin&gs_nf=1&pq=excel%20php&cp=0&gs_id=8&xhr=t&q=excel+php&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&client=opera&hs=066&rls=ru&channel=suggest&oq=xcel+php&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=696d579c269aa12a&biw=1680&bih=863

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первоначально давайте уточнять - на какой стороне будет работать "парсер" таблицы? Сервер или клиент? И почему PHP, JS? Вообще-то таблица Excel является COM-объектом, для доступа к его свойствам, методам, событиям используется соответствующая технология. Вы объясните, как Вы собираетесь "конвертировать" таблицу - а далее будет видно.

Comment: М... 1)Пользователь на странице сайта нажимает кнопочку "Загрузить таблицу", открывается диалоговое окно, он выбирает нужную таблицу, жмет "ок". 2) *МАГИЯ* 3)Таблица отображается в браузере.
Какими методами будет загружаться/преобразовываться(на клиенте или на сервере) пока что все-равно. Хоть какой-нибудь метод.

Comment: Ну вот и не полностью ответили. Но, частично, судя по вашему ответу - таблица обрабатывается на сервере, а потом, передается Вам. Программа "крутится" на сервере - книги Excel открываются (преобразуются)с помощью PHP, ASP, ASP.NET (при мощной поддержке JS,VBS):).

Comment: Ну.. можно и так. Вот только как?

Answer (score 0):

[@oleg_ismaylov](/users/2122/oleg_ismaylov), Вам правда нужны эти заморочки типа использования каких-то php-шных библиотек или прочей ереси? Есть ведь небезивестный https://docs.google.com/

Там что хотите храните, открываете общий доступ и будет всё то (как я понял) что Вы и хотите

Comment: Зря Вы им так профессионально ответили. Они же ничего не понимают. Если я не прав, поставьте мне очень много минусов. Мой ответ данному пользователю смотрите ниже.

Comment: Пользователю Oleg_Ismaylov сообщаю, что существует два варианта предоставить пользователю таблицу Excel: 1-й - "прогнать" через сканер и послать по "майлу" - данный вариант подходит для ЛУЗЕРОВ! 2-й - вариант для "нормальных пацанов" - просто взять и изучить объектную модель MS Office - далее можно работать!!! ... И все будет замечательно!!!

Comment: Вячеслав, я читаю все ответы и комменты, как правило. Этот раз - не исключение из него) И судя по комментам @oleg_ismaylov он не очень силён в том, о чем спрашивает. Есть задача - её нужно максимально быстро решить. Разбираться как работает PHPExel или ещё что-то там это отнюдь не самый быстрый способ решить задачу, когда есть гуглдокс